# Is it possible to fit (frequentionist) Gaussian model with known variance of residuals?

Tags: r, linear-model, residuals, heteroscedasticity, gaussian-process

Is it theoretically possible to fit a Gaussian model if we already know variance, that is, variance of outcome is not inferred but is known a priori and is defined for every measurement of outcome variable (it is inhomogenous).

If it is theoretically possible, is there any implementation in R?  In other words, can we have custom variance-covariance matrix with fixed variance component?

Comment: Could you clarify? You have the variance associated with each measurement, but you also have the full variance-covariance between the measurements?

Comment: Covariance can be assumed to be zero, or eventually unknown.

Comment: If 0, look into weight least squares, if unknown, it might be more difficult because you would need to estimate those values ... if those values are fixed though, look into the gls command in R.

Comment: Thanks for comment, in WLS you define variance up to a multiplicative constant, so it is not exactly the same thing

Comment: Sure, but your estimates should be related. Refer to the first section on the equal effects model: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:rma_vs_lm_lme_lmer.

Comment: Thanks for the link, there is indeed some relevant information

Comment: "Gaussian model" covers a very large territory: please be more specific concerning what model you are asking about.